# Disable Text Entry - angular with jquery

Tags: angularjs, controller

Found these perfect solution here: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj5cU/3/)

```
// Catch all events related to changes
$('#textbox').on('change keyup', function () {
    // Remove invalid characters
    var sanitized = $(this).val().replace(/[^-.0-9]/g, '');
    // Remove non-leading minus signs
    sanitized = sanitized.replace(/(.)-+/g, '$1');
    // Remove the first point if there is more than one
    sanitized = sanitized.replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g, '');
    // Update value
    $(this).val(sanitized);
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
```

but i can't make this work inside a controller.

How can it be done?

Comment: Always post relevant code here at SO.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is use ng-change in your input like this:

```
<div ng-controller="yourCtrl as ctrl">
    <input type="text" id="textbox" ng-change="ctrl.doSomething()" ng-model="ctrl.someVar">
</div>
```

in this way you will have access to the value of the input inside your controller that can be like this:

```
angular.module('yourModule').controller('yourCtrl',[function(){
    var self = this;

    self.doSomething = function(){
        //you can access the value of the input using
        // self.someVar
    }
});
```

The ng-change (official doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D ) is "executed when input changes due to user interaction with the input element".

---

You can also use the ngKeyup (official doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup ) that is "evaluated upon keyup" how you connect it to a function is the same as ng-change. You will have only to choose one of the two.